# Connecting webservice via WSDL using wsdl2code throws java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:

Tags: java, soap, android-ksoap2, wsdl2code

This is not duplicated a question. I tried using ksoap2-android. its working without any issue.

It happens only on code generated by WSDL2Code @ http://www.wsdl2code.com. I tried many WSDLs:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL
- http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL All WSDLs from demo
- http://www.wsdl2code.com/SampleService.asmx

It always throws an exception:

> wsdl2code throws java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
>
> java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 
>        at java.net.URL.(URL.java:176)
>        at java.net.URL.(URL.java:125)
>        at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.(ServiceConnectionSE.java:65)
>        at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.getServiceConnection(HttpTransportSE.java:206)
>        at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:125)
>        at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
>        at com.Wsdl2Code.WebServices.TempConvert.TempConvert.CelsiusToFahrenheit(TempConvert.java:177)
>        at com.Wsdl2Code.WebServices.TempConvert.TempConvert.CelsiusToFahrenheit(TempConvert.java:162)
>        at com.notification.android.testwsdl.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:38)
>        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 1):

I noted that Code2WSDL generates empty url.
Here is Snippet of generated code from `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL` :

```
    public class TempConvert {

        public String NAMESPACE ="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/";
        public String url="";
        public int timeOut = 5000;
        public IWsdl2CodeEvents eventHandler;
        public SoapProtocolVersion soapVersion;
...
```

Just assign proper URL which is here in my case:
`http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx`

That will solve the problem .. I've already reported this issue.

I hope that may help and save others' time.

Good luck,'.

Answer (score 0):

The tool Code2WSDL generates empty url.
So put the url in the empty String url="" resolve the problem.